# php restructing an array

Tags: php

Given my Array

```
array [0]
    fielda: cca
    fieldb: my value b
    fieldc: my value c
    fieldd: my value d

array [1]
    fielda: cca
    fieldb: my value b
    fieldc: my value c
    fieldd: my value d

array [2]
    fielda: cca
    fieldb: my value b
    fieldc: my value c
    fieldd: my value d

array [3]
    fielda: ccb
    fieldb: my value b
    fieldc: my value c
    fieldd: my value d

array [4]
    fielda: ccb
    fieldb: my value b
    fieldc: my value c
    fieldd: my value d
```

Is there a simple way to restructure it so that fielda is grouped like so

```
array [0]
    fielda: cca
        array [0]
            fieldb: my value b
            fieldc: my value c
            fieldd: my value d
        array [1]           
            fieldb: my value b
            fieldc: my value c
            fieldd: my value d
        array [2]                   
            fieldb: my value b
            fieldc: my value c
            fieldd: my value d
        array [3]                   

array [1]
    fielda: ccb
        array [0]
            fieldb: my value b
            fieldc: my value c
            fieldd: my value d
        array [1]           
            fieldb: my value b
            fieldc: my value c
            fieldd: my value d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there's a simpler way, but this should work for you:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $values) // $array is your original array
{
    $new_array[array_shift($values)][] = $values;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/M26yBLL4

Comment: But the key isn't supposed to be the value of `fielda`, is it? In the second example, the key is `fielda` and the value is `cca`, for example.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Actually, isn't this correct? You had me second guessing myself but now I'm not sure if I should be. OPs syntax is confusing.

Comment: I agree that the question isn't entirely clear in this regard. :/

Comment: Well I see Chris Bricker's answer gives the same output with a different method, so at least I'm not alone :D

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

$restructured = array();

```
foreach( $myarray as $value ){
    $key = $value['fielda'];
    unset($value['fielda'];
    $restructured[$key][] = $value;
}
```

Fyi: I am responding from my phone - pls forgive any typos/autocorrects, etc...

Comment: Except I don't think this what he wanted. `fielda` isn't supposed to be the new key, it's supposed to be a *value* whose key is also `fielda`.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: I interpreted the question the same as Wesley Murch, but I think I like Wesley's solution better - more exegant, etc...  User391986's post was not a real PHP array - this generated comments by Golz and Jason who (sort-of) suggested he repost using print_r();  Also, in user391986's second example the exact structure he proposed isn't really possible with key-value pairs.  I assumed he added 'fielda' as a hint of what he had wanted as an end result.